# Catch SQLSRV execution plan with PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, sql-execution-plan

I have a need to analyze execution plans of the queries a piece of code creates, before actually running them.
I am using PHP8.1, PDO, SQL SERVER ODBC 17 drivers.
on the same connection I first run **and execute** `SET SHOWPLAN_ALL ON`.
Then on the second call I run a query (for development purposes, a very simple one) `SELECT * FROM itay.kokooko1`
Both calls are on the same connection, but not on the same batch. i.e. two separate calls to the `\PDOStatement->execute();`.
The result of the SELECT query if I run using PHP, is the content of the table.
If I run this via SQLCMD, I get the execution plan.

SIMPLIFIED CODE:

```
$dns = "bunch of secretive stuff ??? ";
$conn = new \PDO($dns);
$query1 = $conn->query('SET SHOWPLAN_ALL ON');
...
...
$query2 = $conn->query('SELECT * FROM itay.kokooko1');//this returns actual results and not plan
```

The expected result (if I run something similar from sqlcmd) should look like:

```
StmtText                                         StmtId      NodeId      Parent      PhysicalOp                     LogicalOp                      Argument                        DefinedValues              EstimateRows   EstimateIO     EstimateCPU    AvgRowSize  TotalSubtreeCost OutputList                 Warnings Type                                                             Parallel EstimateExecutions
------------------------------------------------ ----------- ----------- ----------- ------------------------------ ------------------------------ ------------------------------- -------------------------- -------------- -------------- -------------- ----------- ---------------- -------------------------- -------- ---------------------------------------------------------------- -------- ------------------
SELECT * FROM itay.kokooko1;                               1           1           0 NULL                           NULL                           1                               NULL                                  3.0           NULL           NULL        NULL        0.0032853 NULL                       NULL     SELECT                                                                  0               NULL
  |--Table Scan(OBJECT:([a].[itay].[kokooko1]))            1           2           1 Table Scan                     Table Scan                     OBJECT:([a].[itay].[kokooko1])  [a].[itay].[kokooko1].[j]             3.0   3.2035001E-3   8.1799997E-5          11        0.0032853 [a].[itay].[kokooko1].[j]  NULL     PLAN_ROW                                                                0                1.0
```

So, the question, how do I need to run the queries to get the execution plan and not running/executing the actual queries.
(I can't just run all the queries manually, they are fully generated by the AI).

**If you have a solution in C# or Java I can translate this to PHP. ODBC is generic.**

Comment: Sounds like you need `set showplan_text on`

Comment: @Stu Same result, unless I am missing something, like should I run them both at the same time? i.e. each query should start with the SET SHOW ... ?

Comment: It applies to the current process, so if you are issuing a new batch that will presumably be on its own spid; Simply execute `set showplan_text on; select * from table;` in a single batch.

Comment: @Stu one of the first thing I tried before I cam here: "SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]The SET SHOWPLAN statements must be the only statements in the batch."

Comment: Ok, that sounds like a specific requirement of the odbc driver, testing using SSMS you can set showplan followed by a query in the same batch. I guess you need to ensure your query text is executed on the same spid, when issuing each batch presumably `select @@spid as spid` will return different values - maybe a connection pooling option.

Comment: @Stu the batch restriction is actually on the server level, not driver. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-showplan-text-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16
I keep digging :-D

Comment: You could try beginning a transaction. Whatever the driver does under water, since transactions cannot span sessions, it would have to somehow make sure the same session remains in use and wouldn't be able to use a different physical connection. Note that you'd have to do `SET SHOWPLAN_ALL OFF` before actually rolling back the transaction, since otherwise you'll get the execution plan for the rollback, which is less than helpful.